# How do I manually revert back to my old theme?

Tags: themes

After changing themes I get

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_editor_style() in /mydir/wp-content/themes/evolve/functions.php on line 8
```

I cannot even login to the administration panel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply  Delete or rename the theme's directory.